# Comparing treatment effect using mixed effect model/gee/offset? Which one is better?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, model, generalized-estimating-equations, observational-study

I think I have seen various posts indicating that comparison of treatment effect in observation studies should employ either longitudinal mixed effect model or GEE.

Suppose each individual is given two measurements $y_1,y_2$ with $y_1$ before treatment and $y_2$ after treatment.

When one should consider $y_2=offset(y_1)+\beta T$ where $T$ is treatment indicator in observational study?

Does mixed effect modeling or GEE have higher power than $y_2=offset(y_1)+\beta T$ modeling here?

Comment: If your study is observational (and not a randomized control trial), Y_post ~ Y_pre + beta * treatment (ie. without relevant covariates) might not make for a convincing analysis, no matter what approach you choose.

Comment: @dipetkov So I should do mixed effect then? I do not think we can always do RCT in general. There are trials in which you can do observations only due to whatever constraint. I will include other covariates in observational study. However, there is no guarantee that they are "relevant" as we do not know they are relevant,.

Comment: No. The simplest approach is what you call $y_2 = \text{offset}(y_1) + \beta T$ and I call regressing Y_post on Y_pre (covariate) + treatment. What I'm pointing out is that whatever the estimate for $\beta$ is, you may have a hard time interpreting it a meaningful way.

Comment: @dipetkov I agree. If this was RCT, life would be relatively easier. So do you recommend me doing mixed effect with T coding treatment with T=0 at pre-treatment and T=1 at post-treatment? Main issue is that sample size is too small to even do propensity score matching.

Comment: Again I answer no. I don't see any benefit to mixed effects for your use case. For the reason I've given above I think you are focusing on an aspect that's not going to make your analysis any better.

Comment: @dipetkov So you believe that mixed effect model on observational study is useless then? What method do you propose beside propensity score matching for observational study?